# How do I display image path stored in database PHP? (Laravel Orchid)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I want to display images in my Laravel Orchid admin panel. Orchid stores the uploaded images in this folder, with the folder name being the date it was uploaded:

```
storage\app\public\2021\04\21\<name>
```

Laravel stores the image original name, path, extension etc in a special table called 'attachments'. It is linked to my main table called 'users' by an id, image_id in 'users' and id in 'attachments'. In my database, the path is stored as the date, e.g:

```
2021/04/21/
```

I did this SQL join query to retrieve the image:

```
$image = $user->image_id;
$images = DB::table('users')
          ->leftJoin('attachments', 'users.image_id', '=', 'attachments.id')
          ->where('users.image_id', '=', $image)
          ->get(['name', 'original_name', 'path', 'extension']);
            
            foreach($images as $image)
            {
                
                $image_url = $image->path.$image->name.'.'.$image->extension;
                return "<img src='{$image_url}'
                <span class='small text-muted mt-1 mb-0'>{$image->original_name}</span>";
            }
```

I can display the original name however the image does not display. I would like to know if there is anything wrong with the way i retrieved the image. Thank you.

Comment: Looks as if the `<img` tag is missing a closing `>`, and it might need a size (width and height)?

Comment: your image tag is mising a `>` and i think you're missing your project root in your url. it should be something like this: `127.0.0.1:8000/publc/path/to/folder`

Comment: When you inspect the broken link/missing image in the browser, what do you see? An incorrect path or an empty path?

Comment: @Andrew the path being output is correct, however when I opened it in a new tab, it says  the page does not exist.

Comment: @BillJustin did you mean I have to put 127.... to my path as well?

Comment: As long as the ```APP_URL``` in your ```.env``` is correct you should not need to fully qualify the url with the root, just make sure there is a leading ```/``` within your path in in ```img``` tag. Can you post the resulting link you are getting when you inspect the page?

Comment: @andrew yes, yes `http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/2021/04/12/12876b4a034032120b0a3cc3972f19cf2411aaaf.png` the long string after the date is the name of the image given by Laravel for one of the images

Comment: @qwertyuiop it looks like your url does not match the directory where your images are stored. where did the `/admin` came from? can you try doing `http://127.0.0.1:8000/public/2021/04/12/`?

Comment: `/admin` is the url of my web page... tried doing as you asked and yeah, not found, I guess it's a problem with my image path then

Comment: do `admin/public` or `admin/public/storage`

Comment: @BillJustin ok, turns out the link of the picture when i tried it from the browser does not include the `/admin` part, it is `http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/2021/04/12/12876b4a034032120b0a3cc3972f19cf2411aaaf.png`. I kinda need some guidance here. do i need to register the picture route under  `/admin`?

Comment: You dont have to register a new route. The image url or path points to the directory where your image is stored. If you want to add `/admin` in the url, you can simply add an `admin` directory inside your `storage` directory and store your images there. Your new url will then look like this: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/admin/2021/04/12/image.png`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The public path to your images is configured in your `config\filesystems.php` file.

There will be a section that looks something like this:

```
'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],
```

You likely need to correct the image's path you are saving into the database to match what's configured here, note the 'url' value matches what you mentioned it the working location to your photos.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `$image_url="2021/04/21/12876b4a034032120b0a3cc3972f19cf2411aaaf.png"` and your file is in `/storage/public/2021/04/21/12876b4a034032120b0a3cc3972f19cf2411aaaf.png`

As the image is in storage path you can create a route which response the image.

```
Route::get('/image/{path}', function ($path) {
   return \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage::disk('public')->response($path);
})->where('path', '.*')->name('show.image');
```

And replace your `return "<img src='{$image_url}'` with `return "<img src='{route('show.image',['path'=>$image_url])}'`

Comment: Image still does not display, and for some reason when I inspect the code, the image source also include the `route....`